# dynamic hintText not displaying in ios in appcelerator app

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Dynamically set hintText for textarea is not displaying in ios app created using appcelerator titanium.Please advise any alternative. However it works fine in android.

```
    if (rowId == 1 ){         
        $.remarktextarea.hintText = "Input Remarks";    

    } else if (rowId == 2) {           
        $.remarktextarea.hintText = "Add Annotation";  

    }
```

Comment: Whenever you ask a question which involves coding, always provide some code snippets so users can understand what you are doing & what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HintText property of a textarea is not supported on iOS, as you can see in the [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextArea-property-hintText)

I'd recommend placing a label on top of the textarea with the styling you want your hinttext to have, and add `touchEnabled: false` to the property, so users can't click on it (but the click will go through to the textarea instead).

Then watch for changes on the textArea `<TextArea id="remarktextarea" onChange="handleChange" />` and hide and show the hinttext based on length:

```
function handleChange(){
    $.hinttextlabel.visible = $.remarktextarea.value.length == 0
}
```